# Different forward, backward and strafing speed

Tags: unity-game-engine

I use this code to make my fps character move:

```
CharacterController controller;

void Awake()
{
    reference = new GameObject().transform; 
}   
void Update()
{
    controller.Move (moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);
    reference.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, mycamera.eulerAngles.y, 0);
    forward = reference.forward;
    right = new Vector3(forward.z, 0, -forward.x);
    float hor = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
    float ver = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
    targetDirection = (hor * right) + (ver * forward);
    targetDirection = targetDirection.normalized;
    targetVelocity = targetDirection;

    if (inputDetected)
    {
        targetVelocity *= speed;
        moveDirection.z = targetVelocity.z;
        moveDirection.x = targetVelocity.x;
    }
}
```

This works great, but I want my character to have a different forward, backward and strafing speed. I've tried `targetVelocity.x *= speed1;` and `targetVelocity.z *= speed2;` but that didn't work. The moment I move my mouse, the character doesn't go forward anymore when pressing the forward key, but slantwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That doesn't work because forward is not the same as the z value of the velocity vector. The values in the velocity vector are world space values.

The easiest way to achieve what you want is to apply the speed difference directly to your inputs. So for example (Not the best solution but just to give you a quick idea)

```
float ver = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"); //-1 to 1
float forwardSpeedMultiplier = 1f;
float backwardSpeedMultiplier = .6f;

//If input >= 0 then use forwardspeed multiplier
// else use backwardspeedmultiplier
float speedMultiplier = (ver >= 0) ? forwardSpeed: backwardSpeed;

//Multiply input value with the multiplier
ver *= speedMultiplier;
```

EDIT

Here's the better version

```
public class Move : MonoBehaviour {
    public float forwardMultiplier = 1.2f;
    public float backwardMultiplier = .5f;
    public float sidewardMultiplier = .7f;
    public float speed = 5f;

    private Rigidbody rb;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        var input = transform.rotation * new Vector3(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));        
        var dotResult = Vector3.Dot(input.normalized, transform.forward);
        var speedMultiplier = (dotResult >= 0) ? Mathf.Lerp(sidewardMultiplier, forwardMultiplier, dotResult) : Mathf.Lerp(sidewardMultiplier, backwardMultiplier, Mathf.Abs(dotResult));
        var movementVector = input * speed * speedMultiplier;
        movementVector.y = rb.velocity.y;
        rb.velocity = movementVector;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Had to remove `targetDirection = targetDirection.normalized;` too to make it work. Why do you say this is not the best solution? What are the drawbacks?

Comment: @binoculars  Sorry for the confusion, i didn't mean its necessarily a bad way, its just a basic version. 
For a more optimal solution i'm thinking in the direction of (Untested)
 
 var forwardMultiplier = 1f;
 var sideMultiplier = .8f;
 var backwardMultiplier = .3f;
 var inputVector = transform.rotation * new Vector3(hor, 0, ver);
 var forward = transform.forward;
 var dotResult = Vector3.Dot(inputVector.normalized, forward);
 var speedMultiplier = (dotResult >= 0 )? Mathf.Lerp(sideMultiplier, forwardMultiplier, dotResult) : Mathf.Lerp(backwardMultiplier, sideMultiplier, dotResult);